# How to create in xamarinforms/android what will remind you of a call in IOS?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am creating an application in which I have calls, when a call occurs, my application shows a notification like in the picture below.

Pictures for example!!! I do for android

[image: notification]

The problem is that the notification is hidden in the curtain on its own, although the call is still in progress, but I need it to be displayed all the time while the call is in progress. For example, like on the Iphone, something like this

[image: notification ios]

Below is the standard code for building the appearance of a notification that I use.
I thought about how to extend the time when the notification is displayed on the screen, but have not found a solution yet ((

```
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
         .setContentTitle("New mail from " + sender.toString())
         .setContentText(subject)
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
         .setLargeIcon(aBitmap)
         .build();
```

Comment: You can use the SetOngoing method of the Builder to make the nitification display only with the cancel methed.  If you need more information, please according to this [link](https://forasoft.com/blog/article/how-to-make-a-custom-android-call-notification-455)

Comment: I'm glad to provide you some help. Has your prblem been solved?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Yes